# How do you replace the entire items of a mongodb collection and with a Javascript array?

Tags: mongodb

1. I have an original mongodb collection that looks like this that populates in my app:

   {"_id": "57d5af7de3a3885aa7381380", "name": ["Barry Allen", "Bruce Banner",
    "Clint Barton",
    "Arthur Curry",
    null]}

How can I replace my mongodb collection with a javascript array that looks like this:

```
       var newRoster = 
       ["Peter Parker", "Susan Storm", "Victor Stone", 
       null, "Jennifer Walters];
```

I tried doing this in my js file.

```
        $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',

        url: '/students',

        data: {
            updatedRoster: newRoster,

        },

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if (response == 'success'){
                alert('Successfully updated');

            } else {
                alert('Error');
            }
      } 

    });
```

I tried going this in my node file.

```
    app.post('/students', function(req, res){
    db.students.update({"name": req.body.updatedRoster},
    function(err, docs){
        if (err) throw err
        res.send('success');
    });
});
```

Comment: Looking through your own question history, you've never once accepted an answer, even though you've commented that answers have solved your problems. In order for SO to function properly, you should upvote and select answers that have helped you. I would suggest going back through you question history and doing so to answers that fixed your problem.

Comment: I tried voting or commenting but I wasn't sure how. Do you just click on the arrow up next to the answer to vote?

Comment: yup, just click the up arrow next to the answer to upvote it, and click the checkmark next to the answer if the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first object in the update function is a selector. It tells mongoDB which document you want to update. The second object is used to tell mongoDB how you want the found document(s) to be changed.

So, try this:

```
// client
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',

    url: '/students',

    data: {
        _id:          id,
       updatedRoster: newRoster
    },

    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response == 'success'){
            alert('Successfully updated');

        } else {
            alert('Error');
        }
  } 

});

// server
app.post('/students', function(req, res){
    db.students.update(
        { "_id": req.body._id },
        { $set: { "name": req.body.updatedRoster } },
        function(err, docs) {
            if (err) throw err
            res.send('success');
        }
    );
});
```